# How to convert DateTime to a number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, type-conversion

How can I get the total number of seconds since `'1970-01-01 00:00:01'` from a DateTime instance in MySQL?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You are looking for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

> If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC.

Comment: That converts a Datetime, which in general do not need to be UTC. If you need to convert a local Datetime, this answer must be edited. Check my answer.

Comment: Also, as documentation says "The valid range of argument values is the same as for the TIMESTAMP data type: '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC. If you pass an out-of-range date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), it returns 0."

Answer (score 7):

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP( dateField )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`value`, '%Y%m%d') AS `date_ymd` FROM `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 6):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)` force a localization of the datetime, which unlike the timestamp, is stored "as is".

You need actually any of the following, for discarding the UTC correction:

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(datetime, '+00:00', @@session.time_zone))`

or:

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',datetime)`

Refs: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql), [2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html), [3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql)