# How to calculate timestampdiff with param from table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want calculate a "dynamic" timestampdiff where params are in tables and I have to make a query for extract it. Both params are stored like datetime. I try commands like this:

```
 timestampdiff(second,now(),'select date1 from dates where id=1;');
```

and the result is ERROR 1064, SQL Syntax error.

I have search in Google and SO and I have find some interesting comments in this question [Calculate difference between two datetimes in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-datetime-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close here.  What you need is

```
SELECT timestampdiff(second,now(),date1)
  FROM dates
 WHERE id=1
```

Your attempt put a text string with your SQL statement in the third actual parameter to `timestampdiff()`. MySQL attempted to parse that as a datetime constant and gacked.

Comment: Certain, I see the error few seconds after post the question. Your answer work fine. Thanks @OllieJones