# How to calculate differences of two columns with timestamp format?

Tags: sql, timestamp, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to create a column differences of two columns with timestamp format.

I have col1 and col2, need to generate column "diff(hous)", as shown in picture highlighted part. Thanks.

[image: pls see example]

Comment: Standard SQL does not have time functions - they are implemented by each database provider (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc.). Please add the appropriate tag to know which functions you need,

Answer (score 1):

[Calculate the time difference between two timestamps in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863144/calculate-the-time-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-mysql)

So you need to first create an empty new column, and then populate it by doing a TIMESTAMPDIFF.
Something like that :

```
UPDATE table SET newcolumn = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,col1,col2);
```

Something like that

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF() returns integer values. The requirement is decimal values.

Comment: Well, then you could use a different unit and make the calcul by yourself maybe ?
Something like TIMESTAMPDIFF(FRAC_SECOND,col1,col2)/3600000;

Comment: Got this: SELECT Failed. 3706: (-3706)Syntax error: Data Type "FRAC_SECOND" does not match a Defined Type name.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, try replacing FRAC_SECOND by MICROSECOND
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Also replace the 360000 by a 3600000000 (has micro second is a smaller unit)
You could also use SECOND and divide by 3600, but you will get a smaller precision

Answer (score 0):

Note that your "diff(hours)" values actually represent days, not hours.

Teradata does not provide a native timestamp difference function but you can calculate by extracting the parts and doing simple math:

```
select col1, col2,
cast((cast(col1 as date) - cast(col2 as date)) as float)
+cast((extract(hour from col1) - extract(hour from col2)) as float)/24
+cast((extract(minute from col1) - extract(minute from col2)) as float)/24/60
+cast((extract(second from col1) - extract(second from col2)) as float)/24/60/60
as diff_days
from myTable;
```

You could put the calculation into a SQL UDF if you need to use it multiple places.

Comment: Note that there is a separate `teradata` tag for the database itself; `teradata-sql-assistant` is a client tool.