# find timestamp difference between 2 columns with sqldf

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqldf, pandasql

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863597/12304000

We can use something like this in mysql to calculate the time diff between two cols:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(<INTERVAL>,<timestampFrom>,<timestampTo>);
```

How can I achieve the same thing with pandasql? I tried these:

```
from pandasql import sqldf
output = sqldf("select DATEDIFF(minute,startDate,completedDate) from df")
output = sqldf("select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,startDate,completedDate) from df")
```

but they throw an error that:

```
OperationalError: no such column: MINUTE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PandaSQL documentation:

> pandasql uses SQLite syntax.

The link in your post is for MySQL. Here is a reference for SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

The syntax would be like:

`"select ROUND((JULIANDAY(startDate) - JULIANDAY(completedDate)) * 1440) from df"`

Comment: which unit will the difference be here? and how can I change the unit?

Comment: It calculates the difference in days, multiplying it gives you your unit. `* 24` would be hours, `* 24 * 60` would be minutes `* 24 * 60 * 60` would be seconds.