# SQL - Split open & Close time Into intervals of 30 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Purpose: I work in Hospitality Industry. I want to understand at what time the Restaurant is full and what time it is less busy. I have the opening and closing times, I want to split it 30 minute interval period.

I would really appreciate if you could ease help me.

Thanking you in advance

Table

```
Check# Open CloseTime
25484   17:34   18:06
25488   18:04   21:22
```

Output

```
Check# Open Close   Duration
25484   17:34   18:00   0:25
25484   18:00   18:30   0:30
25488   18:08   18:30   0:21
25488   18:30   19:00   0:30
25488   19:00   19:30   0:30
25488   19:30   20:00   0:30
25488   20:00   20:30   0:30
25488   20:30   21:00   0:30
25488   21:00   21:30   0:30
```

I am new to SQL. I am good at Excel, but due to its limitations i want to use SQL. I just know the basics in SQL.
I have tried on the google, but could not find solution to it. All i can see use of Date Keywords, but not the Field name in the code, hence i am unable to use them.

Comment: Did you google this? There are a lot of questions and answers concerning this topic, as example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046814/get-30-minutes-interval-data-between-start-and-end-time-in-mysql

Comment: You must tell us which make and version of SQL you use. The date and time manipulation functions are not standardized. Please [edit] your tags

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this, it works in MySQL 8.0:

```
WITH RECURSIVE times AS (
  SELECT time '0:00' AS `Open`, time '0:30' as `Close`
   UNION ALL
  SELECT addtime(`Open`, '0:30'), addtime(`Close`, '0:30')
    FROM times
   WHERE `Open` < time '23:30'
)
SELECT c.`Check`,
       greatest(t.`Open`, c.`Open`) `Open`,
       least(t.`Close`, c.`CloseTime`) `Close`,
       timediff(least(t.`Close`, c.`CloseTime`), greatest(t.`Open`, c.`Open`)) `Duration`
  FROM times t
  JOIN checks c ON (c.`Open` < t.`Close` AND c.`CloseTime` > t.`Open`);

| Check | Open     | Close    | Duration |
| ----- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 25484 | 17:34:00 | 18:00:00 | 00:26:00 |
| 25484 | 18:00:00 | 18:06:00 | 00:06:00 |
| 25488 | 18:04:00 | 18:30:00 | 00:26:00 |
| 25488 | 18:30:00 | 19:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 25488 | 19:00:00 | 19:30:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 25488 | 19:30:00 | 20:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 25488 | 20:00:00 | 20:30:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 25488 | 20:30:00 | 21:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 25488 | 21:00:00 | 21:22:00 | 00:22:00 |
```

->[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. MySQL functions are different to SQL functions, hence I am unable to us it.

Comment: Hi Jones, Sorry for the delayed reply.                                                                I am using SQL Server Management Studio  -   15.0.18386.0

Comment: I was browsing the Net to find the logic, but could not find it. Most of them were hard coded and did not know to  substitute the hard coded variable with column name / field.

Comment: The output which I need is exactly what Fiddle has mentioned.

Comment: I added an SQL Server version as a separate answer (just in case someone finds MySQL useful too...)

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL Server 2019:

```
WITH times([Open], [Close]) AS (
  SELECT cast({t'00:00:00'} as time) as "Open",
         cast({t'00:30:00'} as time) as "Close"
   UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(minute, 30, [Open]), dateadd(minute, 30, [Close])
    FROM times
   WHERE [Open] < cast({t'23:30:00'} as time)
)
SELECT c.[Check],
       iif(t.[Open] > c.[Open], t.[Open], c.[Open]) as [Open],
       iif(t.[Close] < c.[CloseTime], t.[Close], c.[CloseTime]) as [Close],
       datediff(minute,
                iif(t.[Open] > c.[Open], t.[Open], c.[Open]),
                iif(t.[Close] < c.[CloseTime], t.[Close], c.[CloseTime])) Duration
  FROM times t
  JOIN checks c ON (c.[Open] < t.[Close] AND c.[CloseTime] > t.[Open]);

Check  | Open              | Close             | Duration
25484  | 17:34:00.0000000  | 18:00:00.0000000  | 26
25484  | 18:00:00.0000000  | 18:06:00.0000000  | 6
25488  | 18:04:00.0000000  | 18:30:00.0000000  | 26
25488  | 18:30:00.0000000  | 19:00:00.0000000  | 30
25488  | 19:00:00.0000000  | 19:30:00.0000000  | 30
25488  | 19:30:00.0000000  | 20:00:00.0000000  | 30
25488  | 20:00:00.0000000  | 20:30:00.0000000  | 30
25488  | 20:30:00.0000000  | 21:00:00.0000000  | 30
25488  | 21:00:00.0000000  | 21:22:00.0000000  | 22
```

->[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=92d049e1bbe49a196265703c118791a3)

Comment: Thank you Kombajn zbożowy for taking time to help me. I am able to modify this code for any time interval - 20 minute interval or hourly, etc.