# SQL Select data between date and hour in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL column like this:

```
| id | name | date | hour |
```

I want to select all names between specified `start_date`, `start_hour` and `end_date`, `end_hour`.

For data like this:

```
| 1 | one   | 2014-12-29 | 11:00 |  
| 2 | two   | 2014-12-30 | 09:00 |  
| 3 | three | 2014-12-30 | 11:00 |
```

Values:

```
start_date = 2014-12-29
start_hour = 11:00
end_date = 2014-12-30
end_hour =  10:00`
```

It should return: `one, two`.

Comment: If you can save your date time as a timestamp then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql link would help you.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  date > '2014-12-28'
       AND hour > '10:59'
        AND date < '2014-12-31'
           AND hour < '10:01'
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a basic sql query.  try the following:

```
select a.name 
       from (select * from data_table 
                      where date >= start_date
                      and   date <= end_date) as a
       where a.hour >= start_hour
       and   a.hour <= end_hour
```

the basic idea is to first form a data set of all valid days for all times and then from there pull out the valid times.  The other possibly more direct method would be to create a datetime field and then pull on that key.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works only for the same hours in all days and that's not exactly what I want. Creating a new field will be propably the best solution.

Comment: are you trying to do this in sql or are you programming in something like php or c?  If you're in a programming language you could try using a for loop.  That way for each start and end date you could have a unique start and end time.