# How to subtract two sql datetime fields

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I have two datetime values on sql database and I want to subtract them and get the difference as a number of hours.

So far I have created three values. Deptime and ArrTime as datetime values and here are my questions.

1) What value shall the third table be? can it be number because I want to use it for statistics?

2) How can I subtract the Deptime and Arrtime and store the differnce in the FlightTime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which dbms? date/time are often product specific.

Comment: It is an sql database

Comment: You mean MS SQL Server? (SQL is a language, not a product.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two datetimes in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 10):

DATEDIFF can get you your hours.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, Deptime,Arrtime ) AS FlightTime FROM YourTable.
```

Comment: Most probably a very noob question but I will write this code to the SQL code inside my phpmyadmin or on the code I write for the web application?

Comment: Likely in your web app. Especially if you plan on doing it multiple times, on computing these hours on the fly.

(Heh. Fly.)

Comment: As I understand it's MySQL implementation of SQL. So `DATEDIFF` would return difference in days.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tSQL then you could use the DATEDIFF function. You can use this function with hours but if you want fractions of hours then you can use minutes and then convert back to hours.

fraction of hours

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Deptime,Arrtime) AS DECIMAL(30,10))/60 AS FlightTime
FROM TableName
```

whole hours

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(HOUR, Deptime,Arrtime)) AS FlightTime
FROM TableName
```

Since it is a calculated field, I would just create a view with the DATEDIFF function for the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has its own DateInterval routines that might give you more flexibility (and portability) than doing it in SQL.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($DepDate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($ArrDate);
$FlightTime = $interval->format('%h');
```

I'm looking at your progress and see a couple of red flags. Since you're accepting user input and inserting it into a database, [you should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) at the very least be using [prepared, parameterized insert statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

```
$PiRepSubmissionSqlQuery = '
  INSERT INTO Pireps (
    PID, FLID, DEPID, ARRID, 
    FlightPlan, AircraftType, Fuel, 
    DepDate, ArrDate, FlightTime, 
    Remarks, Server
  ) 
  VALUES (
    ?, ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ?, ?,
    ?, ? 
  )
';

// This is just an example - don't forget to check for errors
$sth = mysqli_prepare($mydb, $PiRepSubmissionSqlQuery);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
  $sth, 
  'iiiisssssiss', // these should correspond to your SQL datatypes
  $PID, $FLID, $DEPID, $ARRID,
  $FlightPlan, $AircraftType, $Fuel,
  $DepDate, $ArrDate, $FlightTime,
  $Remarks, $Server
);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql function  [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get difference between dates. So your query should look like this:

```
$PiRepSubmissionSqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Pireps (PID, FLID, DEPID, ARRID, FlightPlan, AircraftType ,Fuel ,DepDate ,ArrDate, FlightTime  ,Remarks ,Server) 
                       VALUES ('$PID', '$FLID', '$DEPID', '$ARRID','$FlightPlan' ,'$AircraftType' ,'$Fuel','$DepDate' ,'$ArrDate' ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ArrDate, DepDate), '$Remarks' ,'$Server')";
```