# Convert time to seconds in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert time to seconds in mysql.

```
   IN_datetime           OUT_datetime         Duration
2013-09-14 17:58:50   2013-09-14 18:02:12 =     202

select time_to_sec(out_datetime - in_datetime )  from customer_1.reconcile
```

My output comes as 3280 instead of 202.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two datetimes in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

Try use this code:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2013-09-14 17:58:50','2013-09-14 18:02:12') from test
```

Comment: 2 values should be swapped. Edited.