# How would I extract minutes from difference of two dates that are saved in different columns in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to extract minutes from difference of two dates, but the dates are saved in two columns, say C1 and C2.
I used this command "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(minutes, C1,C2) FROM Table ;"
Its not correct, of course, because it is giving syntax error.
Also I want to extract minutes from difference of date in a colunm and current date.

Comment: *and I want to flag this question as opinion based :P*

Comment: Why ? I searched for on stack also. But the syntax is still showing error.

Comment: do you want that we do your homework? *Also I want to extract minutes from difference of date in a colunm and current date.*

Comment: for more info refer this: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can search it on stack overflow.

somebody already faced same issue and resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql)

example for second or you can use minute (MINUTE): 
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_column_1, date_column_2) from table_name