# How I get difference between 2 times in words like "x hours y minutes z seconds" using mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two time column in a table name is start_time and end_time.

I need difference between these tile. e.g. `start_time  = 18:40:00` and `end_time = 20:50:00`.

output will be `2 hours 10 minutes.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate difference between two datetimes in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function of MySQL

```
SELECT 
TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time) AS duration
FROM your_table;
```

**TIMEDIFF() function**

`MySQL TIMEDIFF()` returns the differences between two time or datetime expressions. It is to be noted that two expressions must be of same type.

**Syntax :**

```
TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

**Arguments**

```
Name    Description
expr1   A datetime value.
expr2   A datetime value.
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the duration in words (e.g. `x hours y minutes z seconds`):

```
SELECT 
CONCAT
( 
IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) > 0, CONCAT(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)), ' hours'),''),
IF(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) > 0 , CONCAT(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)),' minutes'),''),
IF(SECOND(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) > 0 , CONCAT(SECOND(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)),' seconds'),'')
) AS duration
FROM your_table
```

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @end_time := '20:50:00';
SET @start_time := '18:40:00';

SELECT 
CONCAT( 
IF(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)) > 0, CONCAT(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)), ' hours '),''),
IF(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)) > 0 , CONCAT(MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)),' minutes '),''),
IF(SECOND(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)) > 0 , CONCAT(SECOND(TIMEDIFF(@end_time,@start_time)),' seconds'),'')
) AS duration;
```

**output:** `2 hours 10 minutes`

Comment: I need output will be 2 hours 10 minutes.

Comment: isn't it giving you `02:10:00` this? it's 2 hours 10 minutes.

Comment: I know this but can query give me result in format of 2 hours 10 minutes

Comment: 2 hours 10 minutes 0 Seconds preferred? or you don't want words for 0 values. what?

Comment: Only need minutes

Comment: the updated answer work ok. now in this next is there are multiple rows of the start_time and end_time for a date range like 2016-09-01 to 2016-09-30. I want total sum of time between any given range.

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of this question. You can post it as a separate question.

Comment: Please practice marking answer as accepted if this works for you so that others having same problem would find this useful. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @HarendraChaudhary