# How to Subtract current date time from date time in database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project.I have to check " how  many minutes ago ,user updated the database " .For that I used following code :

```html
<?php
include('connect_db.php');

$sql  =" SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE user='john' ORDER BY time_ DESC LIMIT 1" ;    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

       $time = strtotime($row['time_']);

       $current=time();

       $sub_time=$current-$time;

     echo $sub_time;
}
```

The problem is the code is returning negative values like [ -17173  ].
The date-time stored in my db is like [ 2018-07-14 11:42:21.006515 ]

I simply want to compare current time with the the time stored in database get results in seconds or minutes .
I need help to solve this issue.Thank you .

Comment: Your code seems fine, but I'm not sure `strtotime()` can understand your date-time format. The PHP manual is not very helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php I don't see yours there. Why not cut the last bit off, and use the MySQL format? So you're left with this bit: `2018-07-14 11:42:21`.

Comment: The time() function returns the date in UTC. If your database time is in local time, use date() instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can just change your select statement to give you the time difference in seconds as shown below:

```
$sql  =" select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_Timestamp()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_) FROM test_table WHERE user='john' ORDER BY time_ DESC LIMIT 1" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think DateTime is better approach, as it has the methods to achieve the result you need.

maybe something like this:

```
$time=$row['time_'];
$curr_time=new DateTime();
$difference=$time->diff($curr_time);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

***Updated***

You should use the DateTime functions to figure out the difference in time.  You should be able to integrate this into your code.

I incorporated my suggested code as a function into your original code.  This should work for you.

Try this:

```
function timeDiff($date){

  $date     = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)));
  $current  = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
  $interval = $date->diff($current);
  return $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');


}

include('connect_db.php');

$sql  ="SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE user='john' ORDER BY time_ DESC LIMIT 1" ;    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

         echo timeDiff($row['time_']);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You first need to convert them to timestamp. And them subtract them convert the resuting timestamp back to format you want.

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  

       $time = strtotime($row['time_']);

       $current=time();
       $sub_time=date('d-m-y h:i:s',(strototime(date('d-m-y h:i:s')-$time));
       echo $sub_time;
}
```

You need to handle the greater than and less than cases too.