# Calculate difference in dates using JOIN in MySql

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have MySQL table which has `logId` as the foreign key

[image]

The other table has `logId` as one column and corresponding `startDate` and `endDate`

[image]

I want to write a JOIN in a way such that my output provides difference between `startDate` and `endDate` (in hours) for every server.

[image]

I have written the following `JOIN` but need help to calculate to the difference in dates and show it as `TotalTime`

```
select server, totaltime from table1
inner join table2 on table1.logId = table2.logId
```

Comment: Asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907750/calculate-difference-between-two-datetimes-in-mysql

Comment: convert the dates unix timestanps and subtract/divide to reach hours

Comment: but how should I inject `TIMESTAMPDIFF` in my `JOIN` query

Comment: SELECT "test_column", (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-10 18:16:55') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-01-10 17:16:55')) / 60 / 60 as total_time

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.server, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate) AS TotalTime
FROM 
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.logId = t2.logId
```

Answer (score 0):

The function **TIMEDIFF** gives the difference between two time/datetime

```
SELECT 
    servername, TIMEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate) AS totaltime
FROM
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.logId = table2.logId
```